# define some data from another table In phpword Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpword

I have 2 tables:

1. OperationalPlan
2. Report

In OperationalPlan.table "id" = Report.table "op_id"

I use phpword

my code in Controller

```
public function getCloseReporthReport($id)
{
// get the Plan Data
$data = OperationalPlan::findOrFail($id);
// get the Report Data
$data_s = Report::where('op_id',$data->id)->get();
// how can I get all data on table Report By $data->id?
//Example data on Report Table 'target','risk'...
```

I tried :

```
    public function getCloseReporthReport($id)
{
// get the Plan Data
$data = OperationalPlan::findOrFail($id);
// get the Report Data
$data_s = Report::where('op_id',$data->id)->get();
    if($data_s != null)
{
    $tar = $data_s->target;
}else
{
    $tar = "";
}


$document->setValue('target', ($tar) );
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/report/{id}}','Web\HomeController@getCloseReporthReport')->name('report.report.plan');
```

View:

```
<a href="{{ route('report.report.plan',$data->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"
```

Error :

```
Property [target] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is `op_id` defined as primary key on in your `Report` model? Then simple change it to `Report::findOrFail($data->id)` to retrive a single model instance. Remember that `->get()` will return a collection of Report models so you would have to loop over it. More information about Collections [can be found here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-collections)